# REST lookups from Excel

Tags: excel, rest

I end up parsing a lot of excels at work to get data into my database. The process is very error prone, but the users insist on using Excel anyway.

I have a REST interface available for my database which would eliminate some of the problems of mistyped names, or fields that don't match.

What is the recommended way to communicate between excel and the REST interface? (I am mainly LAMP developer, so I am not so knowledgeable on MS technologies. I have had enough experience with Visual Basic to want to avoid it if possible. Is IronPython a possible option here?).

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA, I'm afraid you're out of luck. To my knowledge, there's no standard way for an Excel sheet to communicate with a REST interface. There might be some 3rd party options, though... have you tried a google search?

Comment: Is it acceptable to let the Excel sheet put data directly into the Database?

Comment: It is acceptable to put data into the database. But this is generally the point where errors occur.

Comment: @pnuts Not really: SR.SE is for software recommendations, and it's not at all clear to me that this question calls for a separate tool, rather than a methodology to add the requisite support in an existing program. On a separate note, if you mention SR at all, please always link to the [question quality guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221970/changed-response-to-recommendation-questions).

Comment: @pnuts I'm sorry, that's my mistake. I accidentally copy-pasted the wrong link, somehow. I meant: [the question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336).